# Unable to clear child divs whiles using datatables with form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, datatables

I want to display different tables as per selection in a form. When a selection is made from a form and a button clicked, I want a table to be generated. Each selection results in a different table.

Right now, the tables get generated when a selection is made and the button clicked. However, there are two problems:

1. The tables arrange themselves one below the other (I'd like only one table to be visible when a button is clicked).
2. As I am using datatables, I get the following error if I select something from the form more than once:

   Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

I think both these problems can be solved if I can clear the previous table when a new selection is made. I have the following code:

```
function generateFactsheetFunction(){
    // Selecting the vaccine chosen from the dropdown
    var e = document.getElementById("selectVaccine");
    var selectedVaccine = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

    console.log("selectedVaccine: ", selectedVaccine);

    if (selectedVaccine=="Rotavirus Vaccine"){
        jQuery('#tableDiv div').empty();
        console.log("rotavirus selected");
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#vaccineRotaFactsheet').DataTable({
                /*Hide the dropdown for number of search results to display, pagination*/
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bAutoWidth": false,

            });
            document.getElementById('tableRotaDiv').style.display="block";

        });
    } else if (selectedVaccine=="Polio Vaccine"){
        jQuery('#tableDiv div').empty();
        console.log("polio selected");
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#vaccineOPVFactsheet').DataTable({
                /*Hide the dropdown for number of search results to display, pagination*/
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bAutoWidth": false,

            });
            document.getElementById('tableOPVDiv').style.display="block";

        });

    } else if (selectedVaccine=="Pneumococcal Vaccine"){
        jQuery('#tableDiv div').empty();
        console.log("pneumo selected");
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#vaccinePneumoFactsheet').DataTable({
                /*Hide the dropdown for number of search results to display, pagination*/
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bAutoWidth": false,

            });
            document.getElementById('tablePneumoDiv').style.display="block";

        });
    }

}
```

The code shows no errors. The jQuery empty line prevents the generation of tables. This solves problem 2. How can I get the tables to be displayed?

UPDATE: Removing the parent div and excluding the sibling divs solves problem 1. This is the modified code:

```
if (selectedVaccine=="Rotavirus Vaccine"){
        jQuery('#tableOPVDiv div').empty();
        jQuery('#tablePneumoDiv div').empty();
```

However, I cannot select an entity for the second time (Problem 2) even though no error is generated.

Comment: There is a function to destroy a datable, i think. However, why dont you use Datatable with serverside processing? Looks like it will solve all your problems. No need to destroy and rebuild table

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm using a triplestore as a database. I didn't come across any applications of server side processing with such triplestores. Can you please direct me to one if you have come across any?

Comment: Add `destroy: true` to the list of DataTable initialization options. Although it makes sense to initialize data tables only once and then show/hide table container on drop-down selection change. It's hard to say without HTML and understanding when `generateFactsheetFunction` is called.

Comment: Adding destroy:true doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using Gyrocode's advice:

```
"Although it makes sense to initialize data tables only once and then show/hide table container on drop-down selection change."
```

This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#vaccineRotaFactsheet').DataTable({
                /*Hide the dropdown for number of search results to display, pagination*/
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "destroy": true,

            });

        });

    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#vaccineOPVFactsheet').DataTable({
                /*Hide the dropdown for number of search results to display, pagination*/
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "destroy": true,

            });


        });

    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#vaccinePneumoFactsheet').DataTable({
                /*Hide the dropdown for number of search results to display, pagination*/
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "destroy": true,    

            });

        });

function generateFactsheetFunction(){
    // Selecting the vaccine chosen from the dropdown
    var e = document.getElementById("selectVaccine");
    var selectedVaccine = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

    console.log("selectedVaccine: ", selectedVaccine);


    if (selectedVaccine=="Rotavirus Vaccine"){
        document.getElementById('tableOPVDiv').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('tablePneumoDiv').style.display="none";
        console.log("rotavirus selected");
        document.getElementById('tableRotaDiv').style.display="block";


    } else if (selectedVaccine=="Polio Vaccine"){
        document.getElementById('tableRotaDiv').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('tablePneumoDiv').style.display="none";
        console.log("polio selected");
        document.getElementById('tableOPVDiv').style.display="block";


    } else if (selectedVaccine=="Pneumococcal Vaccine"){
        document.getElementById('tableRotaDiv').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('tableOPVDiv').style.display="none";
        console.log("pneumo selected");
        document.getElementById('tablePneumoDiv').style.display="block";

    }

}
```